# Declaring struct within another struct and accessing issue when declared as private

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to implement a private struct or class  within another struct. Case I works whereas case II is possible after declaration all member variables as public. why so? I am aware that by default all member variables/functions in struct are public and vice versa in a class definition. Now I am a bit confuse why case II don't work? Any thought?

```
// case I   
struct impl::playlist
{
     struct 
     {
        char name_[30];
     }pod_t;

};

// case II   
struct impl::playlist
{
     class pod_t
     {
        private:
        char name_[30]; // not accessible by impl member func if private 
     };

};
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `public:` in case II?

Comment: It works if declared as public in case II even declare friend don't seem to work

Comment: And what are your doubts specifically then? I don't get what you're confused about.

Comment: Since pod_t struct /class is declared within struct impl shouldn't its member variables be accessible? It is not accepting even declaring protected or friend class; it works only after declaring all member variables as public which looks absurd.

Comment: _"Since pod_t struct /class is declared within struct impl shouldn't its member variables be accessible?"_ No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Case I works whereas case II is possible after declaration all member variables as public. why so? (not accessible by impl member func if private)

Only public members are accessible outside the class. Since member function of `impl` is outside the class `pod_t`, only public members of `pod_t` are available.

---

P.S. Your case I and II are different besides the access specifier of the member. In case I you have an object by the name `pod_t` whose type is an unnamed class. In case II you have a class by the name `pod_t` and no objects of that class.

Comment: Then why shouldn't declaring impl as friend work then ( I tried it as well)? I have opted for case I however.

Comment: @seccpur you have no friend declaration in your example.

Comment: You nailed it. Accepted as answer